# How do I embed an image in a twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an image embeded in an email via swiftmail. I am using a twig template for the content.
I followed the example in the swiftmailer documentation but was unsuccessful.  The image is not being displayed in the position I want (i.e. the middle table).

**twig template**

```html
<body>
  <table class="main" bgcolor="purple">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="lside" bgcolor="white">
          <tr>
            &nbsp;
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="middle" bgcolor="white">
          <tr><td>
            <img src= {{image_src}}, alt="Image" />
          </td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="rside" bgcolor="white">
          <tr>
            &nbsp;
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**swiftmailer**

```
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('Templates');
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);

    // Create the Transport
    $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('outgoing.ccny.cuny.edu', 587, 'tls'))
      -> setUsername('email name goes here')
      -> setPassword('email password goes here');
    $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $message = new \Swift_Message('Newsletter');
    $data['image_src'] = $message->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath('documents/newimg.jpg'));
    $msg = $twig -> render('newsletterTemplate.html.twig', $data);
```

**email output**

[image]

Comment: It's seems to be a problem of css? I can't see any relation with symfony, twig and swiftmailer

Comment: @goto see my update.  Also, The only styling I have is a border around the tables

Comment: How does the fact than your image is not displayed how you would like linked to the framework or the email transport? It's just a problem of style, You should change your tags to html/css.

Comment: @goto I don't what tags I need to change to html/css.  If I take the contents of the twig template and put it directly into the setbody() method it works.

Comment: Problem solved!!   The quotes  around {{image_src}} in the twig template were missing.....